# How to Change SVG color in SCSS using currentColor

Tags: css, svg, sass

How can user the currentColor to fill the svg? i want to use the current element color in the svg background like this:

```
.icon {
 color:bleu;
&::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 19 15" fill="currentColor"> <polygon points="9 14 1 14 1 1 9 1 9 4.5 10 4.5 10 0 0 0 0 15 10 15 10 10.5 9 10.5 9 14"></polygon> <polygon points="14.708 3.146 14.011 3.854 17.113 7 4.5 7 4.5 8 17.113 8 14.011 11.146 14.708 11.854 19 7.5 14.708 3.146"></polygon> </svg>');
    width: 19px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: 14px;
    position: absolute; // hide underline on hover
    top: 2px;

}

&:focus {
    &::after {
        position: inherit; // show border on focus and save the top position
    }
}

&:hover {
    color:red;
    &::after {
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 19 15" fill="currentColor"> <polygon points="9 14 1 14 1 1 9 1 9 4.5 10 4.5 10 0 0 0 0 15 10 15 10 10.5 9 10.5 9 14"></polygon> <polygon points="14.708 3.146 14.011 3.854 17.113 7 4.5 7 4.5 8 17.113 8 14.011 11.146 14.708 11.854 19 7.5 14.708 3.146"></polygon> </svg>');
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you may use javascript to set the background image and use css vars instead of currentColor

Answer (score 3):

Using the `url` technique of adding a background image like this creates a new context for the svg to live, effectively making `currentColor` the default browser colour.  So you cannot do it like this.

What you can however do is the following:

1. Set the SVG fill colour to blue `fill="blue"`
2. In the hover, use the `filter: hue-rotate()` to colourize the background

In your case that would be

```
.icon {
  &::after {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 19 15" fill="blue"> <polygon points="..."></polygon> </svg>');
  }

  &:hover {
    color: red;
    &::after {
      filter: hue-rotate(120deg);
    }
  }
}
```

or alternatively just

```
  &:hover {
    filter: hue-rotate(120deg);
  }
```

which will apply the filter to both the icon and the regular text.